# focus() not working for a select box(dropdown)

Tags: javascript, jquery

On some particular event i want to focus on a particular select box. But

```
document.getElementById('myselect').focus()
```

is not working. It is working fine for a text input but not for a select box.

Comment: What is the event? Can u post a jsfiddle demo?

Comment: Can you post the code you tried that doesn't work?

Comment: well it looks ok - check your id is correct maybe?

Comment: What is the behaviour you are expecting here, to open dropdown list on focus or what???

Comment: It is focusing.  Though I agree that we should be able to see the dropdown open.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that it isn't focusing?

I just ran a quick test on jsFiddle with the following code - [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9wswL/):

```
<select name="dropdown" id="dropdown">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">two</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="textfield" /><br />

    <button id="clickme" 
         onclick="javascript: document.getElementById('dropdown').focus()">
            focus dropdown</button>
    <button id="clickme1" 
         onclick="javascript: document.getElementById('textfield').focus()">
        focus textfield</button>

 Pressing the "Focus Dropdown" button does set the focus to the drop down field, but it doesn't actually appear to do anything.  The dropdown field isn't highlighted, although if I press the arrow keys, different values will be selected.
```

Answer (score 0):

it should work and its working.. check the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4gd2K/)

--html--

```
<select id="dpk">
    <option> first </option>
    <option> second </option>
    <option> third </option>
</select>
<input type="button" value="focus Dropdown" id="btn" onclick="my_method()" />
```

--javscript---

```
function my_method()
{
    document.getElementById('dpk').focus();
}
```